# Подменю в Modx

Tags: modx, wayfinder

Здравствуйте!) Имеется [сайт](http://adv-rf.ru/) на modx. Хотелось бы реализовать меня и подменю из дочерних элементов, по типу кликнул по главному меню, открылась страничка с готовым подменю из дочерних элементов, причем при переходе по пунктам подменю на другие страницы, подменю осталось таким же. Т.е. как передать в wayfinder id документа для которого текущая является дочерней? parent и ultimateparent не работают...

Когда я открываю главную страницу подменю появляется, но при переходе по ссылкам из подменю, оно исчезает...

Использую:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &hideSubMenus=`true` &rowTpl=`rowTpl` &outerTpl=`outerTpl`]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение всех проблем:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`[[!UltimateParent?id=`[[*id]]`]]` &rowTpl=`rowTpl` &outerTpl=`outerTpl`]]
```